# Maxval for derived type's variable in array

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have the following array of derived type in Fortran 90:

```
type tpo_line
    integer             :: price    = -1
    integer             :: count    = -1
end type

type(tpo_line),dimension(10000) :: myarray
```

Given a populated `myarray`, is there a more straightforward way to get the `tpo_line` item of the array which has the largest `count` than iterating over the whole array? (I have seen that for simple arrays you can use `maxval`)

Comment: You've asked a few questions recently mentioning "Fortran 90" explicitly.  It's very unlikely your compiler or boss/supervisor will care about that (very old) language revision compared with Fortran 95, 2003, 2008, 2018, so unless you really have a need to restrict yourself to F90 please just call it "Fortran".

Comment: And do not put (Fortran 90) in parentheses into the title, we have tags for that. Or you can make it part of the title, like "in a Fortran array".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will follow those SO guidelines and the advice on not being stuck to Fortran 90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data reference can be an array even when the part on the right is a scalar.  As you can have `MAXVAL(named_array)` you can have `MAXVAL(array_ref)`:

```
print*, MAXVAL(myarray(:)%count)  ! (:) added for clarity but not needed
```

Because the component `count` is scalar we are allowed to have the single part to the left of it an array, and then the reference itself is a (rank 1) array, on which `MAXVAL` happily works.

Similarly, `MAXLOC` and other array querying functions will consider `myarray%count` as a suitable array.

This does not apply when the `count` component is itself an array.